# different ways of querying EF 4?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I m learning EF 4 and have a question about its basics. Please guide me.

I have read some articles and learn to make context using EF 4. What ways I can use to query context ? Are Linq to SQL and Linq to EF different ? I read stored procedures can be used with EF, wat other ways are there and which to chose in which situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard way for querying an EF context is *LINQ 2 Entities*. *LINQ 2 SQL* is a predecessor of Entity Framework and is not intended for use with Entity Framework.

In special cases when *LINQ 2 Entities* is not suitable, you can use [Entity SQL Language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399560.aspx).